# Cannot solve differential equation below

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving for the differential equation:
$\frac{1}{4}z' + xz = x\cdot e^{-x^2}$. 
I realize that I need to take an integrating factor which I found to be $e^{2x^2}$. Could anyone please help me finish solving this diffQ with detailed steps, after taking the integrating factor? Because it seems like I have to do endless integrations by parts. I am sure there must be a faster, more intuitive way, I guess?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

The equation is
$$
z'+4xz(x)=4xe^{-x^2}
$$
After multiplying by the integrating factor we have
$$
z'e^{2x^2}+4xe^{2x^2}z(x)=4xe^{x^2}
$$
Notice the left hand side is just $(ze^{2x^2})'$ by design. So integrating 
$$
ze^{2x^2}=4\int 4xe^{x^2}\mathrm dx
$$
where the integral can be done by parts, and multiplication by $e^{-2x^2}$ will isolate $z$.